# I have a plano convex lens and I want to increase the magnification

Tags: optics, lenses

I have a plano convex  lens and I want to increase the magnification but I cannot increase the focal length can I do this by increasing the curvature and dome height of the lens?

Comment: How can you change the curvature of the lens? You can increase magnification by changing the distance between the lens and the object.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the curvature of the lens will decrease the focal length and increase the magnification. You would have to grind and polish it to a new shape.

It is hard to see how you would increase the thickness of a lens. If you did, you would find that it has a much smaller effect for most single element lenses, and none for a plano convex. Google the Lens Makers Equation for more. [Here](https://www.boundless.com/physics/textbooks/boundless-physics-textbook/geometric-optics-24/lenses-170/the-lensmaker-s-equation-615-4333/) is the first result from a search I did. It gives

$$P = 1/f = (n-1)\left(\frac{1}{R1} - \frac{1}{R2} + \frac{(n-1)d}{R1R2}\right)$$

where 
P is the power of the lens

f is the focal length

R1 and R2 are the radii of the two sides

d is the thickness

n is the index of refraction

For a plano-convex lens, $R2 = \infty$. So the equation reduces to

$$P = 1/f =(n-1)\left(\frac{1}{R1}\right)$$